# FFMPEG - How to seek to percentage of file

Tags: ffmpeg

I've read the documentation to be able to extract a frame using ffmpeg but the command expects me to give it a time and haven't been able to find anything on percentages.

Is there any way I can use a percentage instead of a time so I can use the command globally/in an automated way?

This is the command I'm using: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "INPUT" -frames:v 1 OUTPUT`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify -ss param in fractional seconds. So you can make a script that calculates timestamp in seconds based on required percentage and pass it to ffmpeg command. Here is the example in linux shell

```
INPUT=$1
PERCENT=$2
OUTPUT=$3

LENGTH_IN_SECONDS=$(ffprobe -i $INPUT -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
PERCENT_TO_SECONDS=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($LENGTH_IN_SECONDS*$PERCENT)/100}")

ffmpeg -ss $PERCENT_TO_SECONDS -i $INPUT -frames:v 1 $OUTPUT
```

Usage:
`./percentage_seek.sh ./bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4 49.35 ./out.jpg`

Comment: `Failed to set option '"p' with value '0"' provided to writer context`, fixed with: `csv=p=0`.
I also just use `default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1`.

Comment: My `videoCreateThumbnail.fish` solution: https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/a7db5d3e6e7d543e43705da46ba9c5be